# modifying object value through rvalue

Tags: c++, rvalue, temporary

From Latest C++ ISO Standart
https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr#basic.lval-10

> An lvalue is modifiable unless its type is const-qualified or is a function type. [ Note: A program that attempts to modify an object through a nonmodifiable lvalue or through an rvalue is ill-formed

But the following code below which modifies temporarily through rvalue runs well.

```
https://godbolt.org/z/L9H06i

#include <iostream>
struct A
{
std::string s1;
 A():s1("123") {}
 A&& modify() { s1 = "123411111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"; 
  return std::move(*this);                                                  
   } //modifying temporary object through rvalue!
};

void f(A&& o)
{
   std::cout << o.s1.c_str();
}

int main()
{
   f(A().modify());//modifying temporary object through rvalue!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An rvalue reference isn't necessarily itself an rvalue.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux. What is this then? A().modify()

Comment: @minex: `A()` is a prvalue, but the actual modification is the `=`, which operates on `s1` which is an lvalue.  (Really, it’s whatever assignments to primitive types happen inside `std::string::operator=`, so even `s1`’s value category is irrelevant.)